# Talking with the audience in a show

Tags: voice, voice-leading, production

1. How long is most practical for talking to the audience to create interest?
2. Why talking to the audience is important to create excitement?
3. When is the best timing in a performance for talking to the audience?
4. Where can I found example for artists that thier talk to the audience was boring?
5. How a talk to the audience  can turn to be boring?
6. When is the worst timing in a show to talk with the audience?

Comment: These are all good questions - and I wonder if they are more opinion based and therefore off-topic. In some ways this boils down to asking, "how can I put on a good live show?" Talking or not talking makes a big difference in the overall show. You could go to lots of shows and start taking note of what you like and don't like about how people talk and what about.

Comment: miu - I see all your questions have been closed so far. Please re-read our [about] and [ask] pages, as they give good advice on what is in scope (opinions aren't). Also, please only ask 1 question at a time. thanks.

Comment: IMO: a composer introducing a new work before it is played should take no longer than 25%-50% of the duration of the work.  A fifteen minute exposition on a 7 minute work before you've even heard the piece is excruciating.  Such presentations become extremely boring when they go into too much detail about the structure of the work and how it was composed.

Answer (score 3):

From another form of music performance:  Occasionally an orchestra conductor will chat with the audience about an upcoming piece.  The conductor may want to provide some background on the composer, or the events taking place (e.g., Shostakovich being ordered to write a wartime symphony to stir up patriotism) at the time of composition, etc.
I recall one concert in which the conductor pointed out that a couple themes in one movement were a deliberate satirical jab at a rather boring, pretentious theme in a competitor's earlier symphony.

Similarly,  even a rock or blues band may give a little intro to some song. Well-known examples include the AllmanBros Fillmore concert and J.Geils' expositional opening to "I musta got lost" .

Answer (score 0):

Well, imagine you are [Matt "Guitar" Murphy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matt_Murphy_%28blues_guitarist%29) and are having a stroke on-stage.

That is the perfect opportunity and timing to talk to the audience in order to create excitement and put them on edge.

That way they will appreciate your playing even though you are continuing your set only with one hand, and they will talk about it, like, forever.

Putting that extreme example aside, the purpose of a talk is giving the audience some context for relating to both music and artist.

Personally, I find it among the more embarrassing topics when artists try tying themselves into the locality in some manner, like talking about the great hamburger they were being able to get in some place in this town.